# Is using inheritance like this a bad idea

Tags: java, android, performance, inheritance

Hello I'm inexperienced in programming and learning slowly by making a project for android.

The problem is I'm using a lot of the same code in my activities. Is it a bad idea to share code using inheritance.

example:

```
Class Main extends Activity
       //shared code

           _
Class a     |
Class b     | - extends Main
Class c    _|
```

my usage example:

```
public class Global extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

public void toastMessage(String tMsg, int tLength) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tMsg, tLength).show();
}

public void nextActivity(Class<?> classId, ImageButton btnId) {
    AlphaAnimation alpha;
    Vibrator shake = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if (btnId!= null) {
        alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.5F, 1.0F);
        alpha.setDuration(50);
        alpha.setFillAfter(false);
        btnId.startAnimation(alpha);
    }
    shake.vibrate(50);
    Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), classId);
    startActivity(goToNextActivity);
}
```

Class a,b,c could extend Global and use:

```
  nextActivity(a.class, btnA);
  toastMessage("example", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: There is too little information to say. If it's for learning, just go ahead and try it. If you run into problems you'll know it was a bad choice.

Comment: Added an example of my usage. It works just wondering if its bad for performance/readability.

Comment: If you make `Context` a method parameter you can move the thing into some utility class. (or you could get it from your `ImageButton`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general is not a good idea use inheritance only for code reuse. Inheritance use the "is a" paradigm. Look if is better for you to use Composition. Follow the advice of Matthijs, post always your code.

Comment: I agree that _In general is not a good idea use inheritance only for code reuse_ and I'm surprised by the official doc stating that  _"The idea of inheritance is simple but powerful: When you want to create a new class and there is already a class that includes some of the code that you want, you can derive your new class from the existing class. In doing this, you can reuse the fields and methods of the existing class without having to write (and debug!) them yourself."_ (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) Misleading, I think they should word it better.

Comment: I agree, the documentation is weak in describing the essence of inheritance: in a nutshell, *use an instance of class B 'instead of' (or 'as it is' if you prefer) an instance of class A*.

Few simple questions can be helpful every time we are tempted to inherit from a class:
1.Can the derived class always be used instead of the base class? If not, inheritance does not make sense

2.Can the derived class use the base class interface or needs  a different interface? If no, composition is better

3.Does exist another way to minimize coupling? If yes, prefer the weakest relationship (composition)

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is used to say that a class belongs to some "category" for example:

a class named "goblin" extends the class "enemy". Inside "enemy" there is simple code that applies to all enemys (walking, ai, attacking etc), inside "goblin" class there is code like the graphics, maybe some dialog, animation or stuff that are not shared to all enemies.

There are cases where this is very useful like controlling all enemies, despite some of them are actually goblins or orcs or whatever. About code re-use you can use methods to do it, keep in mind that your code must be easy to read (even if it's just for you) so don't put all steps inside one class, for example (it's going to be a video game example again :P )

```
while(game == true)
{
    getInput();

    moveHero();

    moveEnemies();

    applyGravity();

    drawFrame();
}
```

Even if there are cases like "moveHero" and "moveEnemies" are going to be applied one after another almost always, it's not a good idea to group them together, so you can easily tell what's going on in your program.